# cPanel *user* missing enabled features in x3 theme

Tags: config, cpanel

Basically what I have is a somewhat abandoned virtual hosting account for a client, and the host mostly deals with IT and dedicated hosting. He could really care less for the 3 virtual hosting accounts he's charging $5 a month for, so I don't want to bother him if I don't have to, understandably.

I'm using the x3 theme in cPanel as an admin user, not a host, so I can't get to WHM.

The host enabled all features for me so that I could work on the site uninhibited for a client.  However, some of the features are not showing up in the x3 theme.

SSL Manager and SSL installer are not there. When I enable the Paper Lantern theme, SSL manager is there and usable, but "SSL Installer" is there but not a clickable link. He suggested it's a problem with the theme cache or the config files in the hidden cPanel folder.

I looked at the cached "Enabled Features" and "Disabled Features" and both are in Enabled with a value of "1", and in Disabled with a value of "0".

I looked in the cached feature listing, and "SSL/TLS" is there, set up as an object with "section" value "security", and contains the link and the icon. I cannot see that link in the section.

Now, I don't know what I'm looking for, because I'm just perusing the files, and I haven't been able to find any documentation on the theme configuration. Found a lot of high level documentation, but nothing dealing with scripting the files.

Am I barking up the wrong tree? Or can I do something in the cached files to show these features?

default.v2.cace:

```
pst0
FEATURE-MODULES-PERL
FEATURE-MODULES-PHP-PEAR
FEATURE-CPANELPRO_SUPPORT
FEATURE-SSLINSTALL
FEATURE-SSLMANAGER
FEATURE-WEBDISK
FEATURE-CHAT
FEATURE-ZONEEDIT
FEATURE-CPANELPRO_LEECHPROTECT
FEATURE-MODULES-RUBY
FEATURE-EDIT_COM
FEATURE-SSH
FEATURE-POSTGRES
FEATURE-SETLANG
FEATURE-BBS
FEATURE-PHPPGADMIN
FEATURE-SEARCHSUBMIT
```

x3.en_us.cache

```
...
    "ssl_tls": {
        "width": "48",
        "itemorder": "3",
        "file": "ssl_tls",
        "height": "48",
        "itemdesc": "SSL/TLS",
        "feature": "sslmanager",
        "acontent": "",
        "target": "",
        "subtype": "img",
        "group": "security",
        "searchtext": "SSL/TLS certificate key csr",
        "imgtype": "icon",
        "url": "ssl/index.html",
        "onclick": "",
        "type": "image"
    },
...
    "ssl-manager": {
        "width": "32",
        "itemorder": "3",
        "file": "ssl-manager",
        "itemdesc": "SSL/TLS Manager",
        "height": "32",
        "feature": "sslmanager",
        "acontent": "",
        "target": "",
        "group": "sec",
        "subtype": "img",
        "searchtext": "certificate key csr SSL/TLS Manager",
        "imgtype": "icon",
        "url": "ssl/index.html",
        "onclick": "",
        "type": "image"
    },
```

Comment: I wonder if I can even access these features on a virtual hosting server? Wouldn't any SSL cert affect the other accounts sharing this space?

Comment: CGI CENTER was available in x3 (deprecated) but isn't in paper lantern. Not sure how do rebuild the index for entropysearch.cgi